# Ruby on Rails - add ID parameter to all routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am wondering what is the best way to implement the following functionality in the Rails routing:

Scenario: an website where users sign up for accounts => accountID (Account) becomes the main entity within the website.

Example: https://basecamp.com/:ID/ - takes the authorized users to the Basecamp dashboard. From here all the URLs contain the :accountID as in https://basecamp.com/:ID/projects - list all the projects under the account.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **route prefixing**:

```
scope ":account_id" do
  resources :projects
  ...
end
```

This will always give you params[:account_id] on each resource controller that is defined within the scope.

Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers

**Update:** Here's an entire example including your "dashboard" default route

```
scope ":account_id" do
  root :to => "dashboard#index"  # http://example.com/12323/
  resources :projects            # http://example.com/12323/projects
  resources :todos               # http://example.com/12323/todos
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes - this is what I was looking for. The problem I still have left is how to generate the URLs to add the value of the [:account_id]. Any idea?

Comment: IIRC you just write it like projects_path(@your_account_id) and edit_project_path(@your_account_id, @project) etc

Comment: @CarstenGehling there's an easier way than to append the id to every route in the app. Surely that's a pain in the neck. I believe there's an option to set default params in Rails... no?

Comment: @Mohamad if you have come across the easier way, kindly mention.

Comment: Also you can use `as` option to make naming routes easier - https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-scope