# Set the root route with a changing ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have: `example.com/123`, where 123 can be any string.

How do I set my root route to handle this?

I'm using `get`, but it's not the root. I don't see how to include that `specid`.

```
get('/:specid' => 'outlets/dance#index', :as => :dance)
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the `get` route you have shown? Even if it doesn't specifically say `root` it gets the job done? By the way, if you have a route like this,  you should put it at the end of the routes file so it doesn't intercept other routes.

Comment: The issue is I want to e.g. src and href links to use the root route

Comment: maybe this can be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867314/ruby-on-rails-add-id-parameter-to-all-routes

Comment: Can you share the reason?

Answer (score 0):

the root should be specified. And you can redirect to the show page. For instance, `root 'employees#show', {id: 1}`. This may be help for you.
Or, if you want the params string in url, you can root in routes file like this, let it redirect after root.
`root to: 'dashboard#index', to: redirect('/company_structures/3')`. It will output like `http://localhost:3000/company_structures/3`